# Which JRE when developing with latest JDK update

Tags: java

I am developing software on a machine with the latest JDK update (e.g. jdk1.6.0_24). Do the machines where the software is running also need the corresponding JRE update version? Or would it suffice to have an older version (e.g. jre1.6.0_10) installed?

Comment: FYI latest jdk is JDK 7.

Comment: @Harry, the latest stable release is Java 6 Update 24. Version 7 is still a preview release.

Comment: The release date for Java 7 is widely reported as July 28th, 2011, but I could not find a mention of this on the Oracle web site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the major version (1.6.0) needs to match for Java. It's fine if the update version (10 and 24) is different, the spec is still the same. Although ideally the place where the software will run has the latest update for bug fixes, security fixes and performance improvements.

Comment: Note: Java 6 Update 10 introduced some significant changes (but no API changes), so that should be considered a minimum. Those changes included XML stack upgrades (including JAXB/JAX-WS) and JNLP Applet support.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to worry, if both are the same major version, which is your case, both are Java 6.

However, if you are releasing your software to a client machine, I would suggest you to read the incompatibilities between Java 6 and other Java versions. And, if there is an incompatibility, mention it in your product document.

Please read this document: [Java 6  Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html)